# How to reopen Spring Initializr panel in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

After I use IDEA's springboot initializr to complete the initialization of a springboot project, I found that I need to modify the dependencies. Can I return to the `New Module` panel to modify the dependencies?

[how to return to this panel?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAKtJ.png)

Comment: There is no way to reopen this `New Module` panel, you need to change the pom.xml manually or delete current one and create a new module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add the necessary dependencies to the `pom.xml` file. See the official [documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html) to learn how to manage Maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA.